# Angular Firebase Firestore add new fields to user collection

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular7

I'm new to Angular and I'm having a problem that I think is simple ...

I am making an application for discount coupons, I have a registration with Firebase, and I have in my code so that when registering the information is saved in FireStore, in a collection called "users", where I keep "email", "id "and" Roles "(that way I have different roles),

[image: IMG DEMO]

the case is that I want to add more fields within this collection, example: "telefono", I found a way to add information, but only type (boolean), and I do not know how to pass it to (string), since the phone will have a format + 99-9999 + 999999 and not (true or false), I show you my code.

**apiservice.ts**

```
export class ApiService{

    constructor(
        private afs: AngularFirestore
      ) { }

    estadoChange: boolean;

    }


    updateEstado(key){
      this.afs.doc('users/' + key).update({
        estado : this.estadoChange = !this.estadoChange
      })
    }
```

**private-component.ts**

```
actualizarEstado(key) {
    this.afs.updateEstado(key);
  }
```

**private-component.html**

```
<input type="text" (change)="actualizarEstado(user.id)">
```

With this I add a new field to the collection of the user trying to add the information,

[image: IMG DEMO 2]

But I want to add it as a string, and do not boolean, I hope you can help me, greetings!

Comment: Since `this.estadoChange` in `{estado : this.estadoChange}` is a boolean variable, it is getting stored as a boolean in Firestore. You can provide a string value there to store it as a string. For example, `{estado : "foobar"}`.

Comment: hello, can you please tell me how to add a custom field in the firestore user collection ?